# Facebook Open Graph I want 'shared a photo', 'shared a state', 'shared a video' and share add counting

Tags: video, state, photo, shared

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iun5c.png

i want like this!

but i don't know...

if do you know, plz, how can i do ... plz..

```
NSData *pictureData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dicNewsFeed[@"picture"]]];


params = [@{
              @"source" : pictureData,
              @"object_id" : dicNewsFeed[@"id"],
              @"privacy" : privacyJsonString,
              @"name" : dicNewsFeed[@"from"][@"name"]
              } mutableCopy];


...

path = @"me/photos";


[FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:path
     parameters:params
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                         id result,
                         NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"result : %@", result);
         NSLog(@"error : %@", error);

         ...
     }];
```

just  post, no shared.. so, share no counting..

i want to share.. 'shared a photo', 'shared a state', 'shared a video'

no share..

plz...

if do you know, plz, how can i do ...